# Обобщенный делегат

Tags: c#, делегаты

У меня есть делегат: `delegate T Mess<T,U,V>(U mes,V ho);`.
И допустим есть метод:

```
public static void HeloLala(string mes,string ls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mes);
        }
```

Как создать экземпляр делегата, с такой сигнатурой?

Comment: С какой сигнатурой? Как у метода?

Comment: @ヒミコ, да. Я пытался через `Action`. Но не выходит

Comment: В `generic` нельзя передавать `void`, объявите еще один делегат который не будет ничего возвращать.

Comment: @ヒミコ, спасибо!! Те это невозможно в принципе? А что за тип данных `Action` просто по описанию то что нужно.

Comment: Да, `Action` вам подходит, это просто делегат, такой же как `Func`, их различия в том, что первый, не возвращает данных, а второй может возвращать.

Comment: @ヒミコ, но все же с ‘Action’ я не могу объявить экземпляр делегата